# List all neighborhoods per city in google maps API

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to get all neighborhoods per city from google maps.

For example the following API call tells me that Little Italy is a neighborhood in Manhattan, New York.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Little+Italy

Is there of a way of listing all such neighborhood items that belong in New York, or any other US city.

Comment: There seems to be several ways to return neighborhoods. [**Reference**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871135/returning-neighborhood-based-on-address-with-google-geocoder-api)

Comment: I had a similar project at work and found the Google API neighborhoods were not as robust globally as I needed particularly in Europe and Asia. These guys http://www.maponics.com/ have an excellent API, more robust data, and great customer service but they do charge a pretty penny for it.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Though Google Maps displays such data, the GMaps API does not allow you to "play" with neighborhoods.

You would have to use a third party API to get that kind of information.